# how to make the style of select option like this style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

**hello i have this photo :**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bI6U.png)

i want to make a select option with the same style

```
                    <div class="name">
                      <input class="input1"type="name" required>
                      <label class="label1">First name</label>
                    </div>
```

```
.label1{
  position: relative;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 15px;
  pointer-events: none;
  right: 15px;
  top: -28px;
  transition: .2s all;
}
.input1:focus ~.label1,
.input1:valid ~ .label1{
  top: -49px;
  right: 9px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: #1f52f9;
}
.input1{
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.input1:focus{
  border: 1.5px solid #1f52f9;
}
.input1[type="name"]{
  display: block;
  margin: 30px 0 0 10px;
}
.input1[type="username"]{
  display: block;
  width: 390px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
}
.input1[type="submit"]{
  background:  #4971f6;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding:10px 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin:  40px 0 30px 180px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;

}
.input1[type="submit"]:hover{
  background: #254fdb;
}
```

so i want to make   with the same style which mean when i press inside the select (the placeholder moving to the border and then opens the options)

Answer (score 1):

- I made some changes to class name only to make **this answer general.**
- Here selection for label is done by `+` selector,`.field .input:focus+.label` `.field .input:active+.label`. `focus` and `active` are two states for input. For more information about visit [plus selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp).
- We set `field` to `positon:relative` and made `label` `positon:absolute`. By seeting other cs for `backgroubd-color` and `top`, `right` we can achieve it easily.

```css
.field {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.field .input {
  line-height: 20px;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.field .input:focus,
.input:active {
  border-color: blue;
  outline: blue;
  line-height: 28px;
}

.field .label {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.field .input:focus+.label,
.field .input:active+.label {
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
  color: blue;
  top: -8px;
  padding: 0 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <input class="input" type="name" required>
  <label class="label">First name</label>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but please i want for select option

Comment: @AysarSAlawwad, this works for select also you just need to adjust sizing and padding.

Comment: I have mention already that this is general answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there are a ton of libraries which you can choose from, that provide such ready-to-use components/elements. Secondly, if you need to open a dropdown, then you should have a look at `<select>` tag in html, in which you can provide multiple `<option>` tags, which a user can choose from.

Comment: can you give me an example for these libararies?